# changing a image with mouse positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

I have a image at the top of my page and want it to change from stationary to left then right depending on your mouse position on the page. please help me

Comment: My Code so far only works with clicks
____________________________________________________________________

$(".face_one").click(function(){
   
 $(".face").attr("src", "images/faces/face_one.png"); 
   
});
   
 $(".face_two").click(function(){
   
  $(".face").attr("src", "images/faces/face_two.png"); 
   
 });
   
 $(".face_three").click(function(){
   
  $(".face").attr("src", "images/faces/face_three.png"); 
   
 });

Comment: Here is a tutorial you might find helpful:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#Tracking_mouse_position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to utilize the [`mousemove`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) function on the document and then track the mouse location by using the event parameter.

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hhy5N/).

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
    var mloc = {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
    };

    if( 
        (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()/2) &&
        (mloc.y >= 0 && mloc.y <= $(document).height()/2)
    ){
        //In upper left corner
        //Do stuff
    }else if( 
        (mloc.x >= $(document).width()/2 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()) &&
        (mloc.y >= 0 && mloc.y <= $(document).height()/2)
    ){
        //In upper right corner
        //Do stuff
    } //etc
});
```

[Here's a tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position#Tracking_mouse_position) on mouse tracking.
[Here's a whole bunch](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) of available event stuff.

In particular, here's [`pageX`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [`pageY`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/).